# Surround uploaded image link with div

Tags: images, filters, attachments, links

When you upload image you have smth like this

```
<a href="http://vitya/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/8.jpg">  
<img class="alignnone size-Small x Big wp-image-65" src="http://vitya/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/8-286x398.jpg" alt="8" width="286" height="398" />  
</a>
```

I need it to be surrounded with div

```
<div class="size-Small x Big">
<a href="http://vitya/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/8.jpg">  
    <img class="alignnone size-Small x Big wp-image-65" src="http://vitya/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/8-286x398.jpg" alt="8" width="286" height="398" />  
    </a>  
</div>
```

Plz help, who know how to do this

Comment: Hi AucT, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [image_send_to_editor](http://wphooks.info/filters/image_send_to_editor/) filter hook to achieve what you want.

```
<?php
    add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'imagehtmlchange', 10, 8);
    function imagehtmlchange($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
        // your banny wrote - put your code here
        return $html;
    }
?>
```

Comment: although already did it thx. it was really hard to find it